# Icon to the edge

Tags: android, xamarin

I am new to xamarin and android dev. I have created my own app icon. On device install, the icon gets underlaid by a white circle and my icon gets smaller. I use [romannurik homepage](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=image&foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0.05&foreColor=rgba(96%2C%20125%2C%20139%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(68%2C%20138%2C%20255)&crop=1&backgroundShape=square&effects=elevate&name=icon2), here is a screenshot from my homescreen:

[image: screen] I want my icon to be like the icons marked in green. My icon gets like the ones marked in red.

My question is: how can i create an icon like the ones marked in green

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for "Round Launcher Icons" available in Android 7.1 and above.

1) You will need to create the various icons and place them in your mipmap-XXXX resource folders

2) Then you need to assign the `RoundIcon` property either directly in the manifest or via the `ActivityAttribute`:

```
[Activity(Label = "Scoreboard", 
        Icon = "@mipmap/ic_launcher", 
        RoundIcon="@mipmap/ic_round_launcher",
        Theme = "@style/SplashTheme", 
        MainLauncher = true)]
public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    ~~~
}
```

See the blog post for the details:

Blog post: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/round-launcher-icons-in-android-7-1/

Answer (score 2):

SushiHangover is correct, but the better way to do it is to use adaptive icons. The easiest way to deal with Android icons is to download Android Studio. Once that is done, then create a new project. It doesn't matter what the project is.

After it loads and Gradle does it's initial build, in the left hand menu then right click on "res" and select New -> Image Asset. This will launch a new window.

At the top specify the "Icon Type" as "Launcher Icons (Adaptive and Legacy). Then specify a foreground layer and a background layer and hit next. Android studio will generate all the various icons you need for every version of android.

Last step is to transfer all the mipmap folders into your xamarin project and get them added through visual studio.

You should still specify the RoundIcon like SushiHangover mentioned, but if the app is installed on Android 8.0 or greater it will us the adaptive icon to match the look and feel of whatever phone it is installed on.